# How to properly handle python exception that occurs in the celery task?

Tags: python, exception, celery

I have this call, that possible produces exception

```
def cancel_event(event):
    try:
        event.delete()
    except ErrorItemNotFound:
        pass
```

Now I want to move this function to celery. What is the proper way to handle this exception in celery?

```
@shared_task
def cancel_event_task(event):
    event.delete()
```

EDIT:

Yes, I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611122/celery-exception-handling) question, but I want to know what **is the best** practice for handling exception

Comment: Why can't you do the same thing?

Comment: I can, but my question is not how can I do it, I want to know the best practice for it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Celery Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611122/celery-exception-handling)

Comment: Yes, I know about this question, but I want to know what is the best practice for handling exception