# Celery retry exception errors

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm working on a project that requires me to reschedule tasks and I'm running into a problem. Would appreciate any feedback. I get a **celery.exceptions.Reject** error when attempting to retry a celery task. I've tested with a minimal tasks.py as listed below.

Here is the code.

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery, Task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from django.conf import settings

app = Celery('tasks', broker=settings.CELERY_BROKER_URL, backend=settings.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
    
@app.task(bind=True)
def task_process_notification(self):
    try:
        if not random.choice([0, 1]):
            # mimic random error
            raise Exception()
        requests.post('https://httpbin.org/delay/5')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('exception raised - retry in 5 secs')
        raise self.retry(exc=e, countdown=5)
```

I've tried **autoretry_for=** but get the same error.

**tasks.py**

```
@app.task(bind=True, autoretry_for=(Exception,))
def task_process_notification(self):
    if not random.choice([0, 1]):
        raise Exception()
    requests.post('https://httpbin.org/delay/2')
```

**Celery log / traceback**

```
    [2021-06-19 04:21:19,342: INFO/MainProcess] celery@macbook-pro-16.lan ready.
[2021-06-19 04:21:23,762: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: stocks.tasks.task_process_notification[ff372faa-febf-4d47-8628-2851a740cac3]  
[2021-06-19 04:21:23,765: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-9] stocks.tasks.task_process_notification[ff372faa-febf-4d47-8628-2851a740cac3]: exception raised - retry in 5 secs
[2021-06-19 04:21:23,775: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-9] stocks.tasks.task_process_notification[None]: exception raised - retry in 5 secs
[2021-06-19 04:21:23,777: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-9] Task stocks.tasks.task_process_notification[ff372faa-febf-4d47-8628-2851a740cac3] reject requeue=False: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/stocks/tasks.py", line 303, in task_process_notification
    raise Exception()
Exception

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 721, in retry
    S.apply_async()
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 235, in apply_async
    return _apply(args, kwargs, **options)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 561, in apply_async
    return self.apply(args, kwargs, task_id=task_id or uuid(),
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 774, in apply
    ret = tracer(task_id, args, kwargs, request)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 429, in trace_task
    I, R, state, retval = on_error(task_request, exc, uuid)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 705, in __protected_call__
    return orig(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 391, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/stocks/tasks.py", line 307, in task_process_notification
    raise self.retry(exc=e, countdown=5)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 688, in retry
    raise_with_context(exc or Retry('Task can be retried', None))
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/stocks/tasks.py", line 303, in task_process_notification
    raise Exception()
Exception

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 704, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/stocks/tasks.py", line 307, in task_process_notification
    raise self.retry(exc=e, countdown=5)
  File "/Users/TLK3/PycharmProjects/stratbot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 723, in retry
    raise Reject(exc, requeue=False)
celery.exceptions.Reject: (Exception(), False)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `self.retry` before return celery interrupt processing of the task and tries to restart the current task.

So instead of trying to call `self.retry` use something like

```py
@app.task(
  bind=True,
  max_retries=5)
def task_process_notification(self):
    try:
        if not random.choice([0, 1]):
            # mimic random error
            raise Exception()
        requests.post('https://httpbin.org/delay/5')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('exception raised - retry in 5 secs')
```

A better explanation of this problem can be found in the following answer.
[Celery Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611122/celery-exception-handling)

Comment: This doesn't retry the task on Exception.